# Type Casting List<ChildClass> to List<BaseClass>

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting, wildcard

I have a class structure like this :

```java
public class BaseClass {

}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

}
```

Lets say I have a method getList that returns `List<BaseClass>` :

```java
public List<BaseClass> getList() {
     List<BaseClass> b = new ArrayList<>();
     return b;
}

List<BaseClass> b = getList();
```

I want to make the above method getList() generic so that it can either return an object of type `List<BaseClass>` or `List<ChildClass>` based on some conditions and **assign the returned value to an object of type `List<BaseClass>` only**. The reason for this is that I am dealing with some legacy code where objects are of type `List<BaseClass>` and I want to avoid refactoring them to something like `List<? extends BaseClass>` as this would block existing operations like add() on these list objects.

I understand that `List<BaseClass>` and `List<ChildClass>` are not covarient.

However, using the below techniques I am able to cast `List<ChildClass>` to `List<BaseClass>` and I am confused that how it is happening behind the scenes and whether it is right to do so or not.

Using explicit casting :

```java
List<BaseClass> b = new ArrayList<>();
List<ChildClass> c = new ArrayList<>();
b = c; // gives compilation error
b = (List<BaseClass>) c; // gives compilation error
b = (List<BaseClass>)(List<?>) c; // this works
```

Using Generics :

```java
public List<ChildClass> getChildClassList() {
   // code to fetch/generate list and return
}

public List<BaseClass> getBaseClassList() {
   // code to fetch/generate list and return
}

public static <T extends BaseClass> List<T> getList() {
    if(something) {
        List<ChildClass> c = getChildClassList();
        return (List<T>) c; // this cast is required here.
    } else {
        List<BaseClass> b = getBaseClassList();
        return (List<T>) b;
    }
}

List<BaseClass> = getList(); // This works perfectly fine but,
                             // I dont understand how casting is happening here.
                             // Also with cast to List<T> inside getList how is the final return type determined?
```

Using wildcards:

```java
public List<ChildClass> getChildClassList() {
   // code to fetch/generate list and return
}

public List<BaseClass> getBaseClassList() {
   // code to fetch/generate list and return
}

public List<? extends BaseClass> getList() {
    if(something) {
        List<Child> c = getChildClassList();
        return c;
    } else {
        List<Base> b = getBaseClassList();
        return b;
    }
}

List<BaseClass> = getList(); // Gives compilation error saying incompatible types

// Casting this, however, works fine
List<BaseClass> = (List<BaseClass>) getList();
```

These feel a bit like a hack to me probably because Java does not support doing a direct cast. I am afraid there is a catch here which I might be missing.

Although, these work fine for my use case, is there any implication with this approach that I should worry about?

Is it safe to write such code?

Is it a bad way of writing code? If yes, then how this should be handled?

Comment: "Using generics"  (and "Using wildcards"): you're returning an empty list in both cases, so you could simply replace the method body with `return new ArrayList<>();`. There's no difference between the two list instances.

Comment: That is just for illustration. Actually, these lists will contain objects of the type the list is defined for.

Comment: Where do the list elements come from?

Comment: I updated the code. Hope that makes it clearer. Doesn't matter where they come from, at the end, we will only have a list of either type.

Comment: "Doesn't matter where they come from" the source doesn't, the type does.

Comment: “*as this would block existing operations like add() on these list objects*”—that’s precisely what generics is about. When your `List<? extends BaseClass>` is actually a `List<ChildClass>`, you *must not* add an instance of `BaseClass` that isn’t a `ChildClass`. Correct generic code that is free of “unchecked” warnings won’t allow you to do that. Any sequence of type casts which finally converts a reference from `List<ChildClass>` to `List<BaseClass>` feels hacky, because they *are* hacky. There’s only one exception to the rule, `List<BaseClass> a = Collections.unmodifiableList(b);` Guess why…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any implication with this approach that I should worry about?

With the generic case, yes: you can call `List<ChildClass> list = getList();`, and end up with a list full of things that aren't instances of `ChildClass`.

Fundamentally, you can't do anything that results in a different type being safely returned from the method. The best you can do is the wildcard case:

```
List<? extends BaseClass> list = getList();
```

because everything in that list will either be a `BaseClass` (of some flavour), or null.

You can then safely convert this to a `List<BaseClass>` by copying it:

```
List<BaseClass> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Note that if you were using something like Guava's `ImmutableList`, this "copy" could be free:

```
ImmutableList<BaseClass> list2 = ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
```

Despite the name, `copyOf` returns the parameter, cast, if that is an instance of `ImmutableList`, because this is a safe covariant cast.

---

In terms of converting `list` to a `ChildClass`: there's not much you can do at compile time. You have to turn this into a runtime check:

```
// Throw an exception or something if this is false.
boolean allAreChildClass = list.stream().allMatch(e -> e == null || e instanceof ChildClass);
```

And then make a copy of the list, performing the casting.

```
List<ChildClass> list3 =
    list.stream().map(ChildClass.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you can be certain that `list` isn't going to be used anywhere else, you can simply cast:

```
List<ChildClass> list3 = (List<ChildClass>) (List<?>) list;
```

but you have to be *really* sure that `list` is either not used elsewhere, or otherwise not going to be modified by anything other than the casting code.